# php imploding array help

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am trying to the  implode the userIDs in the $users_in_range array the  problem is it is iploding miles instead of userid

```
<?PHP
$users_in_range = users_in_range($lat, $long, 500, true); 

// implode users into mysql friendly list
$comma_separated = implode(",", $users_in_range);
echo $comma_separated;

// this is just for output while debugging
foreach ($users_in_range as $userid => $miles_away) {
    echo "UserID=<b>$userid</b> is <b>$miles_away</b> miles away from me.<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: How does `$users_in_range` array looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The userid is the key of the array, so you need to do:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", array_keys($users_in_range));
```

Comment: thanks, curious is this bad on performance?  Would I be better off possibly reversing the order the array is created, like switch the key?  If I made miles the key and userid a value, would I be able to sort by the miles key?

Comment: The performance should be fine. You could switch it around and sort with ksort, but you'd have a problem if two users were the same distance away - I'd stick with what you have there.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$comma_separated = implode(',', array_keys($users_in_range));
```