# convert array php in to var

Tags: php, arrays

Hello every body I need you convert an array in to var php, and I don't know where start.

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => unixTime:1445559106
    [1] => price:12.00
    [2] => user:Albert
    [3] => CP:zm

)
```

I want a php var = unixtime, price, user, CP

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you mean you want to turn a array to string use `implode`.

Comment: Do you need to get equivalent of `$unixTime = '1445559106'; $price = '12.00'; $user = 'Albert'; $CP = 'zm';`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php imploding array help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181516/php-imploding-array-help)

Comment: Yes you can @Lucarnosky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrayNew = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    list($key,$val) = explode(':', $v, 2);
    $arrayNew[$key] = $val;
}
// it's unclear but you may now want to perform this next call
extract($arrayNew);

// with extract you now have variables you can access
// ie, from you example there is now $unixTime, $price, $user, & $CP
// perhaps just a preference, but I would rather work with the array..  
// $arrayNew['unixTime'], etc.
```

Comment: I prefer your way of doing it with list() method, much cleaner that way.

Comment: @Barmar also used list()... I use explode's 3rd param to limit the the number of "splits" to 2...  the "value" part could contain ":"

Comment: Excelent example this work, can I use extract to get a separate values, can you help me with a example. Thank you so much apreciate your help

Comment: @user4131013...  I updated my answer to show how extract works

Comment: Excelent example this work, how can I view a value, for example echo $unixTime, Thank you again

Comment: Thank you so much user4131013

Comment: Another question user4131013 how can I delete the simbol " in this array ["unixTime"] => 1445466385
    ["price"] => 12.0
    ["user"] => "Albert"
    ["CP"] => "zm"

Answer (score 0):

You just need do this if you want each array value split into $key_name = $value:

```
$value_list = array(
    'test:value',
    'name:George'
);

foreach($value_list AS $key => $val){

    $split = explode(':', $val);

    $$split[0] = $split[1];

}

print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

This method will give you $name, $test as vars as asked for:

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array:

```
$outArray = array();
foreach ($inarray as $element) {
    list($name, $value) = explode(':', $element);
    $outArray[$name] = $value;
}
var_dump($outArray);
```